# How to write a template class to store different template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class called Data

```
template<class T> 
class Data
{
   vector<T> Data_Container;
...
};
```

I want to define a new class which be able to have multiple types of Data.

```
class Multi_Data
{
vector< Data<???> > Different_Datas;
}
```

If I define Multi_Data as template I will just have one type at a time.
**How I can write a class to be able to add different templates like this**:

```
Data< Type_A > DataA;
Data< Type_B > DataB;
Multi_Data Container;
Container->Add(DataA);
Container->Add(DataB);
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you simply shouldn't do this at all. Creating something that can hold different types is fairly easy, *but* when you get the data out, you generally end up with a messy "switch on type" to sort out what type of item you're dealing with. It's ugly and nearly always counterproductive.

Comment: Is it possible to have a non-template class which has template members. If yes, is that the solution for this problem?

Comment: Data<A> and Data<B> are two different types.  There's no magical Data<?> like in Java.  If you're sure you want to do this though, you could use a modified version of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/any.html that is restricted to just Data types (or only put Data types into it).

Comment: @Hesam, you can definitely do template methods of non template class, and they will be storable in containers together. Is it the solution depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Corbin: Can I define the container as vector<Data<boost::any>> instead of vector<boost::any> which has been suggested?

Comment: In this specific situation, that is probably a better idea actually (as templatetypedef already said).  It will mean that the type being substituted into Data (to way over simplify how templates work :p) will be boost::any, which in a lot of situations would be odd. In this situation though, it would be perfect. It will let you define your Mutli_Data very simply: `typedef Data<boost::any> Multi_Data;`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing looks like a perfect use case for the [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html) library, which provides a type-safe, uniform way of storing objects that are of multiple different types.  I believe that you could use `boost::any` here by making your `MultiData` type store objects of type `vector<boost::any>`, then having a function like this to access it:

```
template <typename T> void MultiData::add(const Data<T>& data) {
    Different_Datas.push_back(data);
}
```

Here, the `boost::any` stores an arbitrary value, while the template wrapper prevents you from inserting values that aren't instantiations of `Data`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, In this way, can I access to member functions of Data class after storing as boost::any. i.e. Different_Datas[0].Get_My_Iterator()?

Comment: Can I define the container as vector<Data<boost::any>> instead of vector<boost::any>?

Comment: @Hesam- Actually, yes!  That sounds like a much better idea. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by a small workaround.

```
class DataA { };
class DataB { };
class DataContainer { };
class DataAContainer : public DataContainer
{
public:
    DataA dataA;
};
class DataBContainer : public DataContainer
{
public:
    DataB dataB;
};

class MultiData
{
private:
    std::vector<DataContainer *> vec;
};
```

However, as mentioned, keeping different kinds of data in one list is a bad idea. I guess, that there's a flaw in the design, check it out again.

Comment: The vector would need to store pointers (or smart pointers) to DataContainer, not instances of DataContainer.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an limited (and fixed) number of types to store you should have a look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
std::vector<boost::variant<Data<Type_A>,Data<Type_B> > > Container;
```

It enables you to use a visitation mechanism without using casts or virtual functions.